# Nested Swift class can't conform to Comparable

Tags: swift, nested

I am trying to implement a simple array based heap but running into issues with the nested Node class. I would like my nodes to be comparable, however, the compiler is complaining that the node class doesn't conform.

import Foundation

`class Heap<E:Comparable> {`

```
var heap = Array<Node<E>>()

init() { }

class Node<E:Comparable >:Comparable {

    var key:E!

    init(key:E) { self.key = key }
}
```

}

`func < <E> (lhs:Heap<E>.Node<E>, rhs:Heap<E>.Node<E>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.key < rhs.key }`

`func == <E> (lhs:Heap<E>.Node<E>, rhs:Heap<E>.Node<E>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.key == rhs.key }`

Answer (score 1):

It complains because of the `Node` class doesn't conform the `Comparable` protocol.

```
protocol Comparable : _Comparable, Equatable {
    func <=(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
    func >=(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
    func >(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
}
```

And one more thing, if you want to use the `self.key` to compare, then the type should conform `Comparable` protocol as well. Here's the sample:

```
class Node<E where E:Comparable>:Comparable {

    var key:E!

    init(key:E) { self.key = key }

}
func ==<E>(lhs: Node<E>, rhs: Node<E>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.key == rhs.key
}
func <<E>(lhs: Node<E>, rhs: Node<E>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.key < rhs.key
}
```

Comment: I believe the key already conforms to the Comparable protocol since the Node class is nested within the heap class and heap is of type E:Comparable. My code works fine when the node class is not nested.

Comment: Yeah! You're right. I didn't notice the `E:Comaparable` already set.